Berserker—(somewhat) quick Crusader variant—take 2
An expansion on my prior berserker variant, based on feedback.

Berserker—Crusader Variant
Many believe berserkers’ fits of rage to be divine blessings—or curses. Even more than crusaders, berserkers follow the whims of fate and are only empowered by dire circumstance.
Alignment: Any nonlawful, including true neutral.
Class Skills: Eliminate Knowledge (history) and Knowledge (religion) from the crusader’s class skills. Add Survival and Tumble to the class skill list.
Class Features
As a crusader of your level, except you do not gain furious counterstrike, indomitable soul, zealous surge, and smite, and Devoted Spirit and White Raven are not berserker disciplines. Instead, you gain the following:
Disciplines: Iron Heart, Stone Dragon, and Tiger Claw.
Berserker Strength (Ex): As the alternate barbarian class feature from Player’s Handbook II, except the activation threshold is based on initiator level (the upgrades at 11th and 20th are still based on class level).
Steely Resolve (Ex): As crusader, except that after 1st, your steely resolve delayed damage pool’s size increases by 5 every even level, instead of every 4th level.
Damage delayed with steely resolve counts towards whether or not berserker strength activates (effectively, while steely resolve delays taking the damage, it does not delay activating berserker strength).
Titanic Resolve (Ex): Starting at 3rd level, you can delay the onset of a disease or poison, a fear attack, an attempt at possession or ongoing mental control (as would be suppressed by protection from evil), or the blinded, confused, dazzled, deafened, entangled, fascinated, fatigued, sickened, stunned, or unconsciousness (including sleep) conditions, until the end of your next turn (just after taking damage delayed by steely resolve). The duration of the effect or condition does not begin until the effect or condition does (the delay does not count against it). Whenever you delay one of these effects or conditions, you also delay 5 damage, which is added to the damage you take from steely resolve at the end of your next turn, but does not count against steely resolve’s limit. Like steely resolve, this delayed damage counts towards activating berserker strength.
Treat conditions separately even if they come from one effect: for example, if you are subject to sensory deprivation (Spell Compendium pg. 182), you can delay both the blindness and the deafness caused by that spell, but you delay 5 damage for each and track them as separate conditions. You can also choose to delay one and not the other, say the blinded condition but not the deafened condition. If you do that, you are deafened, but not blinded, at first, and only become blinded later. Then eventually the deafened condition expires, but the blinded condition still has some duration left to it, so you are blinded and not deafened for a time.
Starting at 7th level, when you would begin a delayed effect or condition and take its delayed damage, you can instead double the damage delayed for that effect or condition, and delay both the damage and the effect or condition for another round. You can delay an effect or condition (and its damage) for a maximum of 2 rounds at 7th, 3 rounds at 11th, 4 rounds at 15th, and 5 rounds at 19th, doubling the delayed damage each time (so 5 damage for 1 round, then 10, 20, 40, and a maximum of 80 damage for 5 rounds).
If you delay an effect, any rounds you delay it count against the maximum number of rounds you can delay any condition it causes. For instance, if you delay drow poison for the maximum number of rounds, you cannot also delay the unconsciousness it causes; you have no rounds left. The rounds delaying an effect do not, however, count for determining how much damage you delay; treat the two as entirely separate for that. So at 11th level, you could delay drow poison 1 round, then take 5 damage and delay the unconsciousness 2 rounds (since your maximum is 3 rounds), and you would eventually take only 15 damage instead of the 20 damage that fully delaying the drow poison for 3 rounds would deal.
Meteoric Resolve (Ex): Starting at 11th level, your titanic resolve can also delay the onset of ability damage, ability drain, energy drain, a mind-affecting ability, or the dazed, exhausted, nauseated, paralyzed, or turned condition. When you first delay one of these effects or conditions, you delay 15 damage instead of 5. The maximum number of rounds you can delay these conditions is 1 round (15 damage) at 11th, 2 rounds at 15th (30 damage), and 3 rounds at 19th (60 damage). Note that if you delay an effect covered by meteoric resolve that causes one or more conditions covered by titanic resolve, you could delay the effect up to your meteoric resolve maximum, and then delay the condition(s) for the remaining time you have in your titanic resolve maximum.
Adamantine Resolve (Ex): Starting at 19th level, you can delay the onset of any effect or condition with titanic resolve. When you first delay an effect or condition that is not listed in titanic resolve or meteoric resolve, you take 30 damage, and such effects or conditions can only be delayed a maximum of 1 round (though you may be able to delay an effect 1 round with adamantine resolve and then delay conditions it causes 2 or 4 more rounds using meteoric or titanic resolve, as normal).


I really don't like that last sentence of Adamantine Resolve. It can easily be read as, "you can never delay that type of effect or condition ever again, feel the built-in nerfing process in action!"
On the other hand, DMs likely to allow homebrew are unlikely to make that kind of argument, I guess...

@From Good point! I think—since no one’s answered yet—I’ll throw in a quick adjust there.

Can a delayed effect be removed, and if so would that also remove the impending damage associated with delaying that effect?

@JoelHarmon A fantastic question, not addressed by the rules (as Phoenix Duck noted). I suppose I wasn’t imagining that you could get out of either, but it wasn’t something I specifically thought of.

This is going to need playtesting.
There are a lot of builds and ideas that can be analyzed mostly in a vacuum to get an idea of what to expect going into playtesting.  However, this is not one of those cases.  This is because most of the issues I foresee with this build have nothing to do with balance.
The big question: Can you remove delayed conditions?
With Steely Resolve, it is possible to remove delayed damage when you are healed.  However, Titanic Resolve et al are ambiguous on this.  It's not even clear whether the delayed damage from a delayed condition can be cured, as it's only "like" Steely Resolve.
My two cents are that you should explicitly disallow condition removal.  Otherwise, this class will be massively too strong with Iron Heart Surge.  At 19th level, for instance, it would be able to IHS death itself, which would be pretty silly.  Even before then, you would be able to mitigate a very significant number of conditions.
Healing the delayed damage from status effects is a bit less significant.  Either it can be healed, which feels inconsistent since the ability itself can't be healed and it's tracked separately from the rest of your Steely Resolve damage, or you can't heal it and it feels inconsistent since you can heal all of your other delayed damage.  Of these options, I think not allowing the delayed damage to be healed is the less problematic option.
The slightly less big question: Iron Heart Surge's janky cousin
Adamantine Resolve has extremely broad wording that is prone to all the same abuses as Iron Heart Surge, plus some.  I don't entirely think it's a bad thing, but here are some screwy situations I can think of:

The Berserker gets grappled by an enemy.  The Berserker, enjoying the use of his greatsword, delays the grappled condition with Adamantine Resolve.  At the end of the Berserker's next turn, the grappled condition kicks in.  Is the condition ignored, since the enemy's grapple attempt was not able to complete?  Does the Berserker suddenly get grappled by the enemy?  What if the enemy doesn't want to grapple the berserker anymore, or already ran or teleported away?  Is the Berserker snapped to the enemy's location and the enemy forced to re-initiate the grapple?

The Berserker steps away from a Fighter, who uses an attack of opportunity to trip the Berserker.  Can the prone condition be delayed?  If so, is the Berserker forced to stop or not?  What if the fighter had used Stand Still, would that be delayed?  Or bull rush?

A Psychic Warrior uses Dimension Swap on the Berserker.  The Berserker chooses to delay the effect.  Does the Psychic Warrior arrive at the Berserker's location immediately, or after the delay?  If the Psychic Warrior arrives immediately, where does the Berserker go after the delay is over?  Does he go to where the power was manifested, or to the Psychic Warrior's current location?

A Psion uses Mind Switch on the Berserker.  Does the entire swap get delayed, or only the movement of the Berserker's mind?

The Berserker is benefitting from Shield of Faith and is targeted by Dispel Magic.  Can the dispel be delayed?  If so, what if Cloak of Chaos is cast on the Berserker right afterwards?  Would the Cloak of Chaos be eligible for dispelling when the delayed Dispel Magic comes due?

The Berserker enters an Anti-Magic Field.  Can the magic suppressing effect be delayed?  If so, how long does it apply to the Berserker if he leaves before the end of his next turn?

If the Berserker can't delay an Anti-Magic Field because it's a property of the area rather than an effect on the Berserker, can they not delay being teleported by a Gate?  What about a Teleportation Circle?  What about Teleport?

The Berserker is being grappled in a dragon's mouth, when the dragon decides to use swallow whole.  The Berserker chooses to delay the swallowed condition, occupying the dragon's mouth and preventing the dragon from eating the Berserker's companions for another round.  This is objectively metal as heck.  I have no questions or concerns, I just wanted to point it out.


I'm not saying these situations are impossible to resolve by the rules as written, but several of them are unintuitive and many of them can lead to some slippery slopes if slightly mishandled.  At the table, where anything can happen at any time, this is a lot of fiddly minutiae to have to handle on the fly.  Plus, I'm only accounting for strange interactions with pure SRD content - splatbooks will increase this exponentially.
Now, the kinds of people who would use 3.5 homebrew based on the Tome of Battle are incidentally the kind of people most likely to be up to this task.  Still, it may end up being a fair cognitive load on the DM depending on how often this kind of janky stuff comes up.
Finally, thoughts on balance
I said this class will need playtesting to really iron out balance, and I stand by that.  However, I do have some predictions on things to look out for.  Namely, that this class seems a bit too strong at low levels.
The Crusader is already well in the running for the single best class in the game before level 7.  Any benefit that you give to such a class at low levels cannot afford to be too good, and I think trading off a set of abilities that tend to be most useful later on for a set of abilities that are immediately useful is a pretty rough proposition.
The problem to look out for is that Titanic Resolve comes out of the gates swinging with an extremely reliable way to shut down several major status conditions at that level.  It can deny sleep, stunning fist, nets, poison, and several other effects and attacks that only really get a chance to shine at low levels.  Plus, low levels are when in-combat healing is still good, so the added damage is less significant.
While the base Crusader can do some of this as well, Indomitable Soul at least requires some stat investment to be good.  Titanic Resolve just works, and it works 100% of the time.  So, since reliability is king, it is better.
So, in summary, I think level 3 may be too early to grant this ability.  Pushing it to level 6, or breaking it up even further and pushing part of it to level 6, may be a good idea.
As regards level 11 and beyond, it's really hard to say.  It will depend way too much on circumstances, build, and how you rule certain ambiguities.
Last note
Anyone willing to try out a variant Crusader is no stranger to bookkeeping for a character, but even then the swarm of delayed effects may get overwhelming without a dedicated tracker.  I'd advise printing out some tracking cards with a damage by turn chart that status effect tokens can be moved across.
Again, because I think it bears mentioning, I think this class just needs a few clean-ups of wording and it will be ready for playtesting.  Godspeed.

Yeah, adamantine resolve might just be untenable. It’s 19th level, so balance concerns are pretty much moot in my mind, but stuff like grappling, dimension swap, and mind switch are dastardly problems. (Though, come to think of it, how does mind switch interact with protection from evil in the first place?) Anyway, I don’t think it’s accurate to say crusader is that strong; it’s really not—but it is the point of balance this is aiming for, so the comparison remains apt. Hm hm. Might not be the right approach at all. Unsure.

@KRyan Being an aficionado of E6 myself, I honestly can't think of a single class that I would say is decidedly better than the Crusader at low levels.  Clerics and Druids probably have a slight edge depending on your campaign, of course, but your DM must really hate martials if Crusader isn't at least in the top 5.

Ultimately, Tome of Battle just has so little material that even in E6 they have a really hard time keeping up with moderate-high optimization of even traditional warriors, to say nothing of magical classes. There’s just nothing Tome of Battle gets that competes well with getting to attack 3-4 times per round with notable bonus damage, and that’s just not that hard to do outside Tome of Battle. And Tome of Battle doesn’t actually provide nearly as much utility as it ought to. (And I say this as a huge fan of Tome of Battle.)
